# App sharing in iOS 5

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, ios

I have shared my App Store account with my family member not to purchase the same app twice. It has been simple so far. Just enter the same Apple ID in two devices.

Now we have iOS 5 and iCloud. Is it possible to use two different Apple ID in App Store and iCloud in the same device?

If it is not possible, how could we share App purchases with personally using own iCloud functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Apple's excellent FAQ on multiple App Store and iCloud Accounts: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4895

Particularly these sections:

- Using the same Apple ID for Store purchases and iCloud (recommended)
- Using an individual Apple ID for iCloud and a (different) shared Apple ID for Store
  Purchases

Answer (score 2):

The iCloud login is separate to the App Store login. You can still log into the same App Store account but different iCloud accounts (for data syncing etc).

Disclaimer: I'm fairly sure this works, but have not tried it and am not aware if there are any caveats yet.